# Python pivot table iterate through each value

Tags: python, pivot

I have an example of data below

```
Temperature Voltage Data
         25     3.3   2
         25     3.3 2.5
         25     3.3 3.7
         25     3.3 3.5
         25     3.3 2.7
         25    3.45 1.9
         25    3.45 1.7
         25    3.45 1.5
         25    3.45   2
         25    3.45 2.9
        105     3.3   3
        105     3.3 3.5
        105     3.3 4.7
        105     3.3 4.5
        105     3.3 3.7
        105    3.45 2.5
        105    3.45 2.3
        105    3.45 2.1
        105    3.45 3.3
        105    3.45   4
```

I would like to iterate through each row to calculate the difference between 2 consecutive data point then count how many times that difference is equal or greater than 1.

Then, print out the number of times that happens per Temperature per Voltage.

Thank you,
Victor

Comment: Hi, you described what is your goal but not what is your problem. You probable won't have a solution that will come for free, you should try to solve your problem and come back if you have any trouble, with a piece of code to debug. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Added np.abs to make sure to take the absolute value of the difference.

You can use pandas `diff` for that, and then `np.where` for the condition:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Temperature': [25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,25,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105],
    'Voltage': [3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45,3.45],
    'Data': [2,2.5,3.7,3.5,2.7,1.9,1.7,1.5,2,2.9,3,3.5,4.7,4.5,3.7,2.5,2.3,2.1,3.3,4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['difference'] = df['Data'].diff(1)
df['flag'] = np.where(np.abs(df['difference']) >= 1,'More than 1','Less than one')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Temperature  Voltage  Data  difference           flag
0            25     3.30   2.0         NaN  Less than one
1            25     3.30   2.5         0.5  Less than one
2            25     3.30   3.7         1.2    More than 1
3            25     3.30   3.5        -0.2  Less than one
4            25     3.30   2.7        -0.8  Less than one
5            25     3.45   1.9        -0.8  Less than one
6            25     3.45   1.7        -0.2  Less than one
7            25     3.45   1.5        -0.2  Less than one
8            25     3.45   2.0         0.5  Less than one
9            25     3.45   2.9         0.9  Less than one
10          105     3.30   3.0         0.1  Less than one
11          105     3.30   3.5         0.5  Less than one
12          105     3.30   4.7         1.2    More than 1
13          105     3.30   4.5        -0.2  Less than one
14          105     3.30   3.7        -0.8  Less than one
15          105     3.45   2.5        -1.2    More than 1
16          105     3.45   2.3        -0.2  Less than one
17          105     3.45   2.1        -0.2  Less than one
18          105     3.45   3.3         1.2    More than 1
19          105     3.45   4.0         0.7  Less than one
```